# IOS: Performance of shaders with dynamic branching in OpenGL ES 2.0 vs 3.0

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

I've got an OpenGL ES 3.0 - based IOS app, which I'm going to port to ES 2.0. It contains shaders with a few costly, I guess, loops and ifs. Though the app performs normally on OpenGL ES 3.0-powered device, I'm not sure if it will perform well on ES 2.0 devices (which I don't have). So I'd like to know how good are the older IOS devices  process dynamic branching constructions in comparison with the newer ones? Has anyone seen some related benchmarks?

Answer (score 2):

This is not much a GLES2 or GLES3 question, since you can use GLES2.0 (or even GLES1.0) on a GLES3.0 device.

This is more about the fragment processing power of the GPU, the amount of fragments you'll need to process each frame, the cycle cost of your shader (which you can evaluate with the PVRShaderEditor tool which you can find on the Imagination Technologies website) and how you read texture(s) in the shader.

The less powerfull ES3.0 compatible device is the iPhone 5S.

So if you currently have constant 60fps on 5S then I would not be much worried for devices like iPhone5 and 4S, you'll probably get between 20 & 30fps or more. On iPad2/3 you may need to use a reduced resolution because those have big screens and the GPU may not follow. 
Now for iPhone4 this is another story ... this device is very slow when trying to do complex things in shaders (more than ~20 cycles kills performance...) and/or if you use transparency a lot (ex: full screen transparent quad(s) displayed over other elements) or if you use render targets for post processes.

If you are at 25/30fps on iPhone5S then I think you cannot hope the app to work properly on less powerfull devices if you do not find a way the reduce the amount of cycles used by you shaders (simplifying those / cutting effects etc.)